# Is using xml onClick with ListenerBinding (lambda) hurting optimization?

Tags: android, android-layout, lambda, onclick, onclicklistener

Normally, the `android:onClick` is `@deprecated` because:

> {@deprecated View actually traverses the Context hierarchy looking for the relevant method, which is fragile (an intermediate ContextWrapper adding a same-named method would change behavior) and restricts bytecode optimizers such as R8. Instead, use View.setOnClickListener.}

However, in one of the updated codelab(Oct 29, 2021) [tutorials for Android](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#5), the dev specified to utilize lambda within the `android:onClick` as such:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setFlavor(@string/coffee)}"
```

I am wondering if the optimization is still possible because it is utilizing Lambda and would not traverse anything to find said code ? Or is it still as inefficient ?

Comment: That one won't be handled by that "fragile" `View` method at runtime. Instead, the data binding framework will process that attribute at build time to generate the necessary code for it, and the resulting layout in your app won't even have that `android:onClick` attribute in it anymore.

Comment: I think my first comment might be a little unclear, so just to specify: those issues in the `@deprecated` message do not apply to `android:onClick` attributes with data binding expressions for their values.

Comment: Hey @MikeM., it is clear. Want to submit your answer and I will accept it. By any chance, you would have documentation for this ? Or how do you find out these information ? Interested in finding new resources to learn from or having documentation to rely on. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if things like that are covered anywhere in the docs or examples. I know it 'cause I'm pretty familiar with how things must work in order to integrate with the existing `View`/`LayoutInflater` mechanisms. I just had a quick read through [the dev page on layouts and binding expressions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions), but I didn't see anything there that describes how the build-time processing actually works. I'll see if I can find something official, if I get some time later on.